# Python import system mechanics for split test and app directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, directory-structure

I am struggling to successfully import my project to the test-suite in my project, as well as being able to run the program from the command-line. I've been able to run my test-suite for some time, under the impression that if the tests work, so does the command-line stuff--evidently this isn't the case. I do not *yet* intend on using my program as a library. The `api.py` acts is the entry-point for the program.

I have a project with the following structure (the same directory hierarchy as [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests)):

```
myapp/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        api.py # depends on commands.py
        commands.py # depends on utils.py
        utils.py
    tests/
        context.py
        test_api.py # depends on api.py
        test_commands.py # depends on commands.py, utils.py
```

In the file `context.py` I have a path modification adding `myapp` to the `PYTHONPATH`, so I can successfully run the tests on my code. Here is the contents of that file

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
import myapp
```

I've tried imaginable import combination I can think of. Far too many to list! I have also perused the Python reference [import system page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), and this [tutorial](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/).

How should I import my dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was the correct layout, I mistook the error for something else. Although for future reference, relative imports in Python 3 must be explicit: when in the `myapp` package directory you can't say `import commands`, you must instead import it as `from . import commands`. This was defined in [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) SO post on the topic. Run your package with `python -m mutil.api` not `python ./mutil/api.py` as the latter won't give the interpreter context of the current path.